# Do all microfacet brdf models diverge at grazing angle?

Tags: brdf, microfacet, ggx

My question follows directly [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59758/microfacet-model-brdf-obtain-extreme-values-at-grazing-angles?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Reading the famous [paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Esrm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.pdf) of Walter, it comes that the plotted curves of figure 13 (in question in the related topic) are not directly the brdf but rather the brdf times the cosines of the reflected angle.

Because the divergence at grazing angle (shown in the related post) is due to the division by the cosines of the reflected angle (common to all microfacets models), I wonder if this is always the case ?

Is there microfacet models with a well shaped brdf lobe at grazing angle ?

Do you know references on this topic ?

Comment: When subsurface scattering is taken into account the cos of the incident angle becomes a multiplier in some models. (but strictly speaking this would be a BSSRDF. Here is a link http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Volume_Scattering/The_BSSRDF.html#fragment-BSSRDFDeclarations-1